# Why would my count statements return only the first columns values in all of the columns?

Tags: t-sql, count, isnull

When I run this select statement it will return all the values correctly in column two, however the remaining columns 3, 4, and 5 return the exact same values as column 2. I'm wondering why that might be? Thanks for your help in advance. In case you must know I am attempting to count the 3 values of all of these fields grouped by school. Counting the 0's, 1's, and NULL's separately.

```
SELECT 
    sch.schoolID,
    COUNT(ISNULL(cm.attendance, 404)) AS 'cmAtt',
    COUNT(ISNULL(cm.allowTeacherRequests, 404)) AS 'cmTeacherReq',
    COUNT(ISNULL(c.attendance, 404)) AS 'cAtt',
    COUNT(ISNULL(c.allowTeacherRequests, 404)) AS 'cTeacherReq'
FROM CourseMaster AS cm
    INNER JOIN Course AS c ON c.courseMasterID = cm.courseMasterID
    INNER JOIN Calendar AS cal ON cal.calendarID = c.calendarID
        AND endYear = 2020
    INNER JOIN School AS sch ON sch.schoolID = cal.schoolID
        --MIDDLE SCHOOOLS
        AND sch.schoolID IN(15,16,17,21,28)
        --HIGH SCHOOLS
        --AND sch.schoolID IN(18,19,20,22)
GROUP BY 
    sch.schoolID,
    cm.attendance,
    cm.allowTeacherRequests
    --c.attendance,
    --c.allowTeacherRequests
ORDER BY 
    sch.schoolID,
    cm.attendance,
    cm.allowTeacherRequests
```

The returned information summed up looks a similar to this:

```
ID  c2   c3   c4   c5
18, 106, 106, 106, 106
```

It should look more like this:

```
ID  c2   c3  c4  c5
18, 106, 90, 80, 210
```

EDIT:
Here's a sample of what is returned. column a is the ID, and b is the count (0,1,NULL). However column b is replicated to c, d, and e. C, d, and e actually hold different counts. I'm trying to figure out why the columns are being replicated to match b.

```
a   b   c   d   e
15  390 390 390 390
15  354 354 354 354
15  29  29  29  29
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data of tables. Also, try using AND sch.schoolID IN(15,16,17,21,28) AND endYear = 2020 and in where clause

Comment: Using `IsNull` in `Count` doesn't make much sense. `Count` ignores `NULL` values, but your code makes even `NULL` countable. Since you use `inner join` there must be a non-null column in each table already, so why not count it?

Comment: Aside: If you uncomment code so that you have `AND sch.schoolID IN(15,16,17,21,28) AND sch.schoolID IN(18,19,20,22)` you'll find few rows that meet both conditions at the same time. If you only plan to use one or the other then it will work.

Comment: @Hobo: Counting NULL is intended and yes I do intend to only use one of those conditions.

Comment: hmmm... this kind of question and answer session makes me not like to help on SE. This isn't a question really. It's "troubleshoot my code". We spend time trying to figure out what the poster is trying to do more than answer a single question. I think a proper way to ask your question would be "how to tally/count different columns with different totals". then add details in your question about how you want to count nulls and such. Not blaming the poster, you just want to get things working. but this system kinda stinks imho.

Comment: @jamie, all the back and forth is actually just indicative of a question that didn't include enough detail out of the chute. There are tons of "troubleshooting" questions that get answered here every day. What this question is lacking is sample data, which was the first thing requested, but which has yet to appear. I'm voting to close as "needs more detail". If the OP would like to rehab the question, here's a good place to start: [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, that was pretty helpful. Excuse my incompetence. I will keep all that in mind for the future.

Comment: @JaySway, no incompetence implied. It's your first question here, and there are ropes to learn. Now, about that sample data.... :)